# Jquery/Js function not working as intended

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, function

This is a jquery function wich works great to add and remove form elements. But it leaves the class "input-group col-md-12 row" behind when I remove an element.

I want to change it so that it removes that aswell when I remove an input field.

Bonus: Getting rid of the "p" tag.

**Jsfiddle(missing some css, so you can only see the class that's being left behind in firebug):**
http://jsfiddle.net/tZPg4/8270/

**Function:**

```
 $('#addScnt').on('click', function() {
          $('<div style="width:104%; margin-left:-4px; margin-bottom:5px;"  class="input-group col-md-12 row" style="padding:0;"><p> <input  class="col-md-12"  id="form-field-1" type="text" placeholder="Milestone"> <a href="#" class="remScnt">Remove</a></p></div>').appendTo(scntDiv);
          i++;
          return false;
        });

        $(document).on('click','.remScnt', function() { 
         if( i >= 2 ) {
          $(this).parents('p').remove();
          i--;
        }
        return false;
      });
      });
```

Comment: What do you mean, "it leaves the class behind"?  Do you want to remove that entire `<div>`, or just remove those classes?

Comment: The entire div, I just wanted to highlight the one that I wanted removed ^^

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can remove the whole block with

```
$(this).closest('.input-group.row').remove();
```

instead of

```
$(this).parents('p').remove();
```

The `.closest()` method searches up the parent chain (starting from, and *including*, the starting point, which in your case is that `<a>` element) for the first element matching the given selector.